# How to convert a (.JAR) file to UML?

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, eclipse-plugin, uml

Please I have a .JAR file, i would like simply to convert this file to a UML. 
I have (NetBeans 6.9.1) and (Eclipse IDE for Java Developers) both installed on my machine.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

P.S: Using some search engines, i found (JAR2UML) plug-in for eclipse but sadly i failed in installing it.

Answer (score 5):

Free [Class Visualizer](http://www.class-visualizer.net/) does exactly that - you load JAR file(s) or compiled classes into the tool and, as a result, you see auto-generated, navigable UML class diagrams.
You can search for any class and browse its content as well as relations.

Comment: The tool is a pain when importing and you cannot delete classes already imported. There is also no way to draw multiple classes together if they are not coupled. However it's pretty fast and looks nice. Tip: package your project as a jar and import it that way.

Comment: Another tip: add your dependencies to classpath (File menu). Then you will (almost) stop having class import errors. I packaged my project with maven once with dependencies and once without. That way you can add the dependencies.jar to the classpath and the other one in the visualizer.

Comment: How do we export the information, besides copying and pasting?

Answer (score 2):

I found the following documentation: http://www.ejb3.org/jar_file_reverse/jar_file_reverse.html
This tool is not free but it works pretty well.

You can also use Topcased but the quality of the reversed information is mediocre and it is not really possible to recreate advanced diagrams from the reversed model.

Answer (score 1):

You wanna make an UML file? or an UML diagram from a Java program ? if it's the second, NetBeans has it's own UML plugin, in the full download version, or find the plugin [here](http://plugins.netbeans.org/PluginPortal/)

Comment: I need to make UML diagrams. Sadly, the Netbeans plugin for UML is no longer available [not built-in i mean]. I am trying to research for some plugins under eclipse.

Comment: Did you try it the way is mentioned here: http://netbeans.org/community/releases/55/uml-download.html ?

Comment: Thanks! I am trying now to install the Netbeans 5.5. It seems after a long intensive research, the new editions after 6.7 do not support the UML plugin anymore. There is a hack around it but it is not generating any effective results for me. I will refer to the old version to see if that will do.

Comment: 5.5 is a too old version, try the 6.0 version, i remembered developed a project with an UML diagram in that version, of course it was along time a go. I'm glad i could help, anything else don't hesitate in asking, best regards !!

Answer (score 0):

if you dont have source code of this Jar file, you can [decompile it](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/) when reproduce UML via netbeans,eclipse UML plugins.Btw I am not sure how correct results of UML diagrams will be.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the list below. Particularly look under the Features section. Some of the tools are free and they support reverse engineering. Some tools go with Eclipse also.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unified_Modeling_Language_tools

Comment: This list includes many tools but I don't see any of them being able to reverse jar file and this list has not been updated because over 30% of the tools has been abandoned !!